# New firebase framework will not allow google map user authorization display

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, firebase, firebase-analytics

Currently firebase will not allow my app to display the user Authorization. userAuthorization will open for a second then it will disappear. In the log it look like it disappears after analytics enable appear.

this is my current code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

    class practiceViewController: UIViewController,GMSMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to turn off analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you follow the steps to turn on debug mode and provide the console log? Here is a quote from the [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start#log_events):

> To view this event in the Xcode debug console, enable Analytics
>   debugging:
>
> In Xcode, select Product > Scheme > Edit scheme... Select Run from the
>   left menu. Select the Arguments tab. In the Arguments Passed On Launch
>   section, add -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled.

There are 3 ways to disable Analytics. You can use a flag on the Info.plist or set it at run time on the [website](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#permanently_deactivate_collection). Please let me know which way works for you.

> 1. If you wish to **temporarily** disable Analytics collection, such as to get end-user consent before collecting data, you can set the
>      value of FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_ENABLED to NO in your app's Info.plist
>      file.
> 2. If you need to suspend collection again for any reason, you can call setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:FALSE and collection is suspended
>      until you re-enable it. (Turn off at run time)
> 3. If you need to deactivate Analytics collection **permanently** in a version of your app, set FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED to
>      YES in your app's Info.plist file.